# How to type narrow a string into a discriminating union using an array?

Tags: typescript

For example, let's say I have the following type and I have a string I want to narrow into a LexemeType

```
export const LexemeType = ['(', ')', '{', '}', ',', '.', '-', '+', ';', '*'] as const;

export type LexemeType = typeof LexemeType[number];
```

Why doesn't the following work?

```
if (str in LexemeType) {
  // use str as LexemeType
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` operator checks the object's property keys, not their values. If you have say `{colour:'red'}` object `in` will return `true` for 'colour' but `false` for 'red'. In case of array properties are indexes, so `3  in LexemeType` will return `true`, but not `'}' in LexemeType`, which will be `false`. What you need is `LexemeType.includes(str)`

Comment: When you say "properties" you presumably mean "property *keys*", since "property" is generally used to mean the key/value pair.

Comment: @jcalz that's exactly what I meant, thank you sir!